# Tying a trait lifetime variable to &self lifetime

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'd like to do something along the following lines:

```
trait GetRef<'a> {
    fn get_ref(&self) -> &'a [u8];
}

struct Foo<'a> {
    buf: &'a [u8]
}

impl <'a> GetRef<'a> for Foo<'a> {
    fn get_ref(&self) -> &'a [u8] {
        &self.buf[1..]
    }
}

struct Bar {
    buf: Vec<u8>
}

// this is the part I'm struggling with:
impl <'a> GetRef<'a> for Bar {
    fn get_ref(&'a self) -> &'a [u8] {
        &self.buf[1..]
}
```

The point of the explicit lifetime variable in the `GetRef` trait is to allow the return value of `get_ref()` on a `Foo` object to outlive the `Foo` itself, tying the return value's lifetime to that of the lifetime of `Foo`'s buffer.

However, I haven't found a way to implement `GetRef` for `Bar` in a way that the compiler accepts. I've tried several variations of the above, but can't seem to find one that works. Is there any there any reason that this fundamentally cannot be done? If not, how can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Tying a trait lifetime variable to &self lifetime

Not possible.

> Is there any there any reason that this fundamentally cannot be done?

Yes. An owning vector is something different than a borrowed slice. Your trait `GetRef` only makes sense for things that already represent a “loan” and don't own the slice. For an owning type like `Bar` you can't safely return a borrowed slice that outlives `Self`. That's what the borrow checker prevents to avoid dangling pointers.

What you tried to do is to link the lifetime parameter to the lifetime of `Self`. But the lifetime of `Self` is not a property of its *type*. It just depends on the scope this value was defined in. And that's why your approach cannot work.

Another way of looking at it is: In a trait you have to be explicit about whether `Self` is borrowed by a method and its result or not. You defined the `GetRef` trait to return something that is *not* linked to `Self` w.r.t. lifetimes. So, no borrowing. So, it's not implementable for types that own the data. You can't create a borrowed slice referring to a `Vec`'s elements without borrowing the `Vec`.

> If not, how can I do this?

Depends on what exactly you mean by “this”. If you want to write a “common denominator” trait that can be implemented for both borrowed *and* owning slices, you have to do it like this:

```
trait GetRef {
    fn get_ref(&self) -> &[u8];
}
```

The meaning of this trait is that `get_ref` *borrows* `Self` and returns a kind of “loan” because of the current lifetime elision rules. It's equivalent to the more explicit form

```
trait GetRef {
    fn get_ref<'s>(&self) -> &'s [u8];
}
```

It can be implemented for both types now:

```
impl<'a> GetRef for Foo<'a> {
    fn get_ref(&self) -> &[u8] { &self.buf[1..] }
}

impl GetRef for Bar {
    fn get_ref(&self) -> &[u8] { &self.buf[1..] }
}
```

Comment: Your code at the end of the answer is pretty much what I currently have and what I'm trying to get away from. The reason I want to do this is a bit convoluted, but comes down to the fact that I need to be able to get slices that outlive the `Foo` that they come from (but not the underlying buffer).

Comment: @fjh I think the key point here is that in the trait, the lifetime has to always have the same "shape" - it can be either the lifetime that the implementor is parameterized on, or it can be the object itself, but it can't be both. In your example, when `Bar` dies *so does the buffer* - the buffer cannot possibly life longer.

Comment: @Shepmaster Yeah, I realise that the reference into `Bar` can't outlive the `Bar` itself, but I was hoping there was a way to get this to work with `Foo` without making an impl for `Bar` impossible. I'm sufficiently convinced that this can't be done now. Bummer, though.

Answer (score 0):

You could make different lifetimes for &self and result in your trait like that:

```
trait GetRef<'a, 'b> {
    fn get_ref(&'b self) -> &'a [u8];
}

struct Foo<'a> {
    buf: &'a [u8]
}

impl <'a, 'b> GetRef<'a, 'b> for Foo<'a> {
    fn get_ref(&'b self) -> &'a [u8] {
        &self.buf[1..]
    }
}

struct Bar {
    buf: Vec<u8>
}

// Bar, however, cannot contain anything that outlives itself
impl<'a> GetRef<'a, 'a> for Bar {
    fn get_ref(&'a self) -> &'a [u8] {
        &self.buf[1..]
    }
}


fn main() {
    let a = vec!(1 as u8, 2, 3);
    let b = a.clone();
    let tmp;
    {
        let x = Foo{buf: &a};
        tmp = x.get_ref();
    }
    {
        let y = Bar{buf: b};
        // Bar's buf cannot outlive Bar
        // tmp = y.get_ref();
    }
}
```